# Pathfinding a maze with the Floyd-Warshall algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm, path-finding, floyd-warshall

I'm trying to use Floyd's algorithm to generate a quickest-route matrix through a maze with 98 waypoints (located at each of the maze vertices). As the algorithm runs, it populates two matrices - the Distance matrix (with the most optimal distance between two nodes), and the Path matrix (with the next node to go to for the most optimal path between any two nodes).

The distance matrix is initialized with an adjacency matrix I generate in previous code. I also generate a data structure containing pointers to each of the four possible neighbor waypoints for each waypoint, but I did not used this data structure in generating the path matrix.

Here's my c# code:

```
        // Initialize distance path matrix
        distanceMatrix = adjacencyMatrix;

        // Initialize path matrix
        int N = (WaypointList.Count);
        pathMatrix = new int[N, N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for (int t = 0; t < N; t++)
                pathMatrix[i,t] = t;

        // Floyd-Warshall algorithm            
        for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                for (int j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
                {
                    int currentCombo = distanceMatrix[i, k] + distanceMatrix[k, j];
                    if (currentCombo < distanceMatrix[i, j])
                    {                            
                        distanceMatrix[j, i] = distanceMatrix[i, j] = currentCombo;
                        pathMatrix[j, i] = pathMatrix[i, j] = k;
                    }
                }
```

I believe I am computing the Path matrix incorrectly, because the bot using the Path matrix generated by this code is failing in the majority of situations (as the Path matrix is telling to to go through a wall, etc).

I've been staring at this code for hours, and I'm stumped as to what I've done wrong. How can I generate the correct Path matrix for use in my maze navigation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting `pathMatrix[i, j] = k`, you are assuming that this means that the path from node `i` to `j` will start by going to node `k`. But in fact, what it means is that the path from `i` to `j` will go through `k` at some point, not necessarily on the first move.

What you need to do is the following, assuming that there's a path from `i` to `j`:

```
target = j
while there is no edge from i to target:
    target = pathMatrix[i, target]
```

This will set `target` to the next node to go to from `i`.

Comment: Is this supposed to go in my pathfinding code, or where I initialize my pathMatrix array? I was under the impression that to find the next node to travel to for a fastest-path, all you had to do was pathMatrix[sourceNode][destinationNode]

Comment: @MarathonStudios: Then you were under the wrong impression. You can do this either during pathfinding, or preferably add a loop to calculate the next node for all pairs `(i,j)` and store it in another matrix after you initialize the other matrices. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction

Comment: Just to confirm, the pathMatrix variable is correctly populated in my original code?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes. Assuming that the graph is undirected, `distanceMatrix` is initialized correctly, and that adding two infinite values from `distanceMatrix` doesn't result in overflow.

Comment: Here's my implementation of path, where i is the current location and j is the target. Seems like it should work, but the path being returned is still not correct.

        public int Path (int i, int j)
        {
            int intermediate = pathMatrix[i,j];
            if(intermediate == j) return j;
            else return Path(i, intermediate) + intermediate + Path(intermediate, j);
        }

Comment: @MarathonStudios: The Wikipedia example which I guess you copied is just pseudocode. It is assumed to return a string or a list of vertex indices. Your version returns a number, so it adds together vertex indices which is meaningless. Either use my code above, or use Wikipedia's code but make sure it's concatenating lists rather than adding numbers.